# Which is the best way to get an array difference from an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of values: `["1", "2", "3"]` which contains essentially the reference of the records stored in this array of object:

```
[
    { id: 1, name: "John" },
    { id: 2, name: "Patrick" },
    { id: 3, name: "Jack" },
    { id: 4, name: "Paula" },
    { id: 5, name: "Sarah" }   
]
```

I would like to return the missing reference from the array of objects, so the result will be: `4, 5`. What I achieved so far is takes all the selected values of the first array from all the `select` available in the html:

```
var selected_options = $('.options-picker')
    .map(function() { return this.value}).get();
```

this will return `1, 2, 3`. How can I extract from the array of objects `4, 5`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and  [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check the object ids against the values in the array.

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: "John" },
  { id: 2, name: "Patrick" },
  { id: 3, name: "Jack" },
  { id: 4, name: "Paula" },
  { id: 5, name: "Sarah" }   
];

const items = [1, 2, 3];

const out = data.filter(obj => !items.includes(obj.id));

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do

```
var a=[
    { id: 1, name: "John" },
    { id: 2, name: "Patrick" },
    { id: 3, name: "Jack" },
    { id: 4, name: "Paula" },
    { id: 5, name: "Sarah" }   
]
var b=['1', '2', '3'];
a.forEach((e)=>{
if(b.indexOf(e.id.toString())==-1)
{
b.push(e.id);
}
})
alert(b)
```